# Hiding a chip from being visible if it's name matches a given condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Im working with angular using the md-chip family of objects. I am working on removing a possible category of chip from a code base but it still needs to be in the system but not visible to the user to modify or remove.

Ideally the chip would not show up if the name part of it is "Null" or matches "Some String". I've looked over all the docuemntation that I can find and have been trying to use several iterations and placements of ng-show and ng-if and nothing has worked.

Sorry if this is a fairly elementary and simple question, I'm still learning these things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.show{
display:block;
}
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

now in your html
you can use showChip to apply condition to add class for showing/hiding the element

```
<md-chip [ngClass]="showChip===true?'show':'hide'"></md-chip>
```